# Weird mount behaviour

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I have a weird thing happening and I can't explain.
first take a look at the attached picture.
[image: Mount Issues overview]

As you can see I have a CentOS based AMS-ASPERA01 server in the DMZ, and I have 6 machines in our Broadcast LAN that should be able to reach it. Of those 6, 3 (2x Fedora Linux 1x Windows) can mount with no problem, no warning. The other 3 are also CentOS 6 servers, all have mounts to other machines on CIFS, and work perfectly with those, but on this one, it won't.

The mount command I use is:

```
mount -t cifs //172.23.54.196/aspera -o rw,user=nobody,pass=nobody,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 /mnt/ASPERA-NEW/
```

Because the 3 machines that do work, I guess the Samba config is sort of correct, but here is the `smb.conf` file:

```
[global]
workgroup = foobar
netbios name = AMS-ASPERA01
server string = %h server (Samba %v)
bind interfaces only = true
log level = 0
syslog only = no
syslog = 0
8panic action = /usr/8th = /storage/internal
force user = nobody
force group = nobody
public = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = true
smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
local master = no
os level = 33
domain master = no
preferred master = no
domain logons = no
socket options = SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072 TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY
use sendfile = true
kernel oplocks = no
strict locking = no


security = share
passdb backend = tdbsam


#=====SHARES=====
[aspera]
comment = All Aspera Shared content
path = /storage/internal/aspera
force user = root
force group = root
public = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0666
directory mask = 0777
```

When I mount with the given command I got messages like: Unable to find suitable address, of Mount connection refused. In the messages log file I got the following message when trying to mount:

```
Dec  2 12:48:32 AMS-PYDIO01 kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Dec  2 12:48:32 AMS-PYDIO01 kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111 or -113
```

I googled error 111 and 113, but couldn't find a clear explanation on it.

What can it be?

Comment: This is very likely a network issue (e.g. routing, firewall).  Perhaps use `tcpdump` on firewall and both ends to see where packets are getting stopped?

Comment: That is a bit out of my hands, but I can ask my Network department to create such a dump.

Comment: You get "Unable to find suitable address" when you cannot reach the server (wrong IP, service down, firewall deny ...). Here I think you 3 hosts are not allowed to connect to the DMZ server through the firewall.

Comment: It seems that way....I'm working with our networking team to get things working.

Comment: Found the common factor on the machines that DO mount and DON't mount correctly.
The servers that can mount, also have full internet access through the firewall (From Broadcast LAN to ip any)
The server that can't mount don't have any internet access at all.....

Thanks for the help guys.